# Switching Integral and Sum

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, summation, absolute-convergence, geometric-series

I want to proof that I can switch this Sum and Integral

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int\limits_{0}^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-nt}dt~~$ for $~ 1 < Re(z) $

to sum it after over n. I tried to use the geometric series by the estimate

$\vert{t^{z-1} e^{-nt}}\vert =\vert t^{x+iy-1} e^{-nt}\vert = \vert e^{ln(t)(x+iy-1)} e^{-nt}\vert =\vert e^{ln(t)(x-1)} e^{-nt}e^{iy\cdot ln(t)}\vert \leq \vert e^{ln(t)(x-1)} e^{-nt}\vert \leq \vert \frac{t^{x-1}}{e^{t}}\vert \leq t^{x-1}$

But this $t^{x-1}\leq 1$ is only true for $t\leq 1$. Where are my mistakes or are there any other ideas for the proof?

Comment: Everything is positive, so you are good to go.

Comment: But can I do this?, cause if t is growing I can´t still use the geometric series, don´t I?

Comment: If you allow infinity = infinity, you are always allowed to swap two integrals/sums/mixtures if the integrands/summands are positive.

Comment: So it is enough to say, that due to the integrand is positiv for all t, the Fubini Theorem gives, that I can switch sum and integral. And I am not in need of geometric series

Comment: Right, you don't need geometric series.

Comment: You did not specify this, but if we assume $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then you are not positive. However, then taking the absolute value (i.e., checking the conditions of Fubini) reduces it to a real problem, where it is fine (however, you do have to check that it gets finite, but that is left for you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand is not  a positive function so there is some justification needed here. We can switch the integral and the sum if we know that $\sum_n \int |t^{z-1} e^{-nt}|dt<\infty$. This reduces to $\sum_n \int t^{x-1} e^{-nt}dt<\infty$. Here we can switch the sum and the integral by Tonelli's Theorem, so we now have to show that $\int t^{x-1} \frac {e^{-t}}{ 1-e^{-t}} dt <\infty$. I leave it to you to show that the integrand here is dominated by $Ce^{-t/2}$ for some constant $C$. This completes the proof.